# accessing proxy inside a proxy object in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

[image]

in the picture are two responses when i query the task object. My use case is that I have to iterate over the response using For:Each, For:Item and render a list in the .html file of {Task.Id}, {Task.status}, {Task.Subject}. Also, in the html can i conditionally make {Task.Id}, {Task.status}, {Task.Subject} dynamix based on fieldset. Can someone help me with the code

The 1st one ("response from search") is when i query the object and display the response in console in the child component (from where the method is called). In the 2nd response ("Event fired and received") I pass the value of 1st response to the parent component dispatching an event and try to console.log. I see it returns a proxy object inside a proxy object. I am unable to iterate over the response.
Can someone pls help me? Thanks in advance